# Get unique image for every user when call default image from query

Tags: mysql, sql

Sorry, long title. 
I have a list for registered users, some with profile pic, some without.
the problem is if user 1 is logged in. Then in the user list, everybody has the same profile image as the user 1.

But If i remove my default caller from the query, every user gets their own picture, but the default.jpg image doesn't work. 
I could just remove the query and the use an if statement on the page, but i really want to avoid that.

```php
            function fetch_users($uid){
            $query = $this->link->query( "SELECT user.id, user.username, user.email, 
            userdetails.profile_img,userdetails.firstname,
            userdetails.lastname,userdetails.location,following.follow_id
            FROM user
            LEFT JOIN   userdetails ON user.id = userdetails.user_id
            LEFT JOIN   following ON user.id = following.follow_id
            WHERE       user.id != '{$uid}' ");
            $users = array();
            while(($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) !== FALSE) { 
   #The row that mess up things#----->$row['profile_img'] = file_exists("img/{$uid}.jpg") ? "img/{$uid}.jpg" :  "img/default.jpg" ;
            $users[] = $row;
        }   
            return $users;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing stuff a lot. In the query you fetch the file name from the table, but in the comment row you use the uid to construct the name. For the former to work with the default image, you could use

```sql
SELECT …
  IFNULL(userdetails.profile_img, "img/default.jpg") AS profile_img,
…
```

This will replace `NULL` values in the table with the path of the default image.

If you wanted to construct image paths from user IDs, then you should use the ID from the result row, not the one of the current user:

```php
while(($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) !== FALSE) { 
  $imgpath = "img/" . $row['id'] . ".jpg";
  if (!file_exists($imgpath)) $imgpath = "img/default.jpg";
  $row['profile_img'] = $imgpath;
  $users[] = $row;
}
```

This will create an image path based on the user id, and fall back to the default if no such file exists.

You could even combine them both:

```sql
SELECT …
  IFNULL(userdetails.profile_img,
         CONCAT("img/", user.id, ".jpg") AS profile_img,
…
```

```php
while(($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) !== FALSE) { 
  if (!file_exists($row['profile_img']))
    $row['profile_img'] = "img/default.jpg";
  $users[] = $row;
}
```

This will use the stored image path where set, but a path constructed from the uid otherwise. It will then use the file named in this fashion, but the default if no such file does exist.

Comment: Such a beautiful solution :), worked fine after some tweaking!
really really nice one. Thank you.